# Numbering a claim within a theorem but not in order

Tags: thmtools

I would like to number a claim within the proof of a theorem, but the proof does not appear right after the statement of the theorem. That is, I would like to generate:

Theorem 1. XXXX

Theorem 2. YYYY

Proof of Theorem 1:
....

Claim 1.1 xxxx

....

I am using thmtools so would prefer to avoid ntheorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, with a `lateproof` environment built upon `proof`, which takes as argument the label corresponding to the theorem we're going to prove.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Theorem,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Claim,
  within=theorem,
]{claim}
\renewcommand{\theclaim}{\thetheorem.\arabic{claim}}

\newenvironment{lateproof}[1]
 {%
  \renewcommand{\theclaim}{\ref{#1}.\arabic{claim}}%
  \begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\ref{#1}]%
 }
 {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This theorem is proved just below.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We do some claims.

\begin{claim}
First claim.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
Second claim.
\end{claim}

The proof is complete.
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}\label{tobeprovedlater}
This theorem is proved later.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
This is an intermediate theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lateproof}{tobeprovedlater}
We do some claims.

\begin{claim}
First claim.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
Second claim.
\end{claim}

The proof is complete.
\end{lateproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]